# Model Fitting and Cross-Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation

I'm training a dataset and then testing it on some other dataset.

To improve performance, I wanted to fine-tune my parameters with a 5-fold cross validation.

However, I think I'm not writing the correct code as when I try to fit the model to my testing set, it says it hasn't fit it yet. I though the cross-validation part fitted the model? Or maybe I have to extract it?

Here's my code:

```
svm = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True, random_state=42)

accuracies = cross_val_score(svm, data_train, lbs_train, cv=5)

pred_test = svm.predict(data_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(lbs_test, pred_test)
```

Comment: You are cross validating `self.svm`? Should it not be `svm`?

Comment: I forgot to delete the `self.svm`. I have this inside a class and didn't wanna copy the entire class

Comment: Probably you need too, we need to see if the self.svm is called before cross validation

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, the `cross_validate_score` doesn't return a fitted model. In your example, you have `cv=5` which means that the model was fit 5 times. So, which of those do you want? The last?

The function `cross_val_score` is a simpler version of the `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate`. Which doesn't only return the scores, but more information.

So you can do something like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

svm = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True, random_state=42)

cv_results = cross_validate(svm, data_train, lbs_train, cv=5, return_estimator=True)
# cv_results is a dict with the following keys:
# 'test_score' which is what cross_val_score returns
# 'train_score'
# 'fit_time'
# 'score_time'
# 'estimator' which is a tuple of size cv and only if return_estimator=True

accuracies = cv_results['test_score'] # what you had before

svms = cv_results['estimator']
print(len(svms)) # 5

svm = svms[-1] # the last fitted svm, or pick any that you want

pred_test = svm.predict(data_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(lbs_test, pred_test)
```

Note, here you need to pick one of the `5` fitted SVMs. Ideally, you would use cross-validation for testing the performance of your model. So, you don't need to do it again at the end. Then, you would fit your model one more time, but this time with ALL the data which would be the model you will actually use in production.

Another note, you mentioned that you want this to fine tune the parameters of your model. Perhaps you should look at hyper-parameter optimization. For example: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/36087/54395 here you will see how to use cross-validation and define a parameter search space.